# Changing value of a specific TD using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I would really like your help.
Couldn't find the solution on past posts.

I am trying to change the text of a specific td in a specific row.

So I got this code which I find the specific row:

```
$('#courses-table tr').each(function () {
    if (this.children[6].innerText == newAssignment[3]) { // check courses
        if (this.children[5].textContent == newAssignment[5].split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')) { // check route

            if (this.children[4].textContent == newAssignment[4].split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')) { // check semester

                console.log(this.getElementsByTagName('td')[3].textContent)
                this.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML = "TEST";
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Now, after i find the row with the specific data, i want to change for example the td in position 5 to be something else.

But .innerHTML don't work for me.

Do you guys have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//assign these outside the cycle for better performance
var route = newAssignment[5].split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
var semester = newAssignment[4].split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');


$('#courses-table tr').each(function (index,element) {
    var rowElement = $(element);     
    var rowChildren = rowElement.children(); //arent those all td ?



    if( rowChildren.eq(6).text() == newAssignment[3] && 
        rowChildren.eq(5).text() == route && 
        rowChildren.eq(4).text() == semester){

        var rowTDs = rowElement.find('td');// isnt this same to row children ?? 
        console.log( rowTDs .eq(3).text() );
        rowTDs .eq(0).html("TEST" );
    }

});
```

Comment: This works ! THANKS! but the issue is when I close the form it deletes the "TEST" we put in the table. using return false don't help. Any suggestion?

Comment: Glad that it works. Please mark the answer as correct it would help my stack reputation. As for the closing the form I need more information about how the form is rendered and what does it mean closing the form. is it a modal ?

Comment: I have my friend, thanks . 
Once i click a row in the table i get the a form and after i put my values there i click a button which puts the values in the correct td but the form won't close and once I close everything is deleted.

Comment: everything in the HTML is memory only and it is deleted if you don't post it to the server to save the changes in a DB or some form of persistent storage

Comment: please, could you edit your answer to include details and explanations from the comments? as currently posted, your answer contains code-only.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the corresponding number commented in the example:

- ➊ The double `??` is a [nullish coalescing operator](https://javascript.info/nullish-coalescing-operator). If `document.querySelector(selector)` is `null` because it couldn't find the first @param it will default to `document.querySelector('table')`
- ➋ The chained [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) are basically `if`/`if else`/`else` conditionals. This particular chain insures that if the selector points to `<table>` it gets redirected to `<tbody>`. We will be using `.rows` property and if `<table>` is referenced then the length of `.rows` will include `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` if they exist.
- ➌ If the last @param is passed as `true` then [`.replaceChildren()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren) will be used to remove all content of target cell.
- ➍ Finally we'll append the HTML/text to the target cell.

  - [`.rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) property to target the `<tr>` by index
  - [`.cells`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) property to target the `<td>`/`<th>` by index
  - [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to insert HTML and/or text

```js
// The numbers are index 0 so if you want to target the 6th row it's index 5
tGrp.rows[5].cells[3].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content)
```

```js
/**
 * @desc locate a table cell (<td>/<th>) of a <thead>, <tbody>, or <tfoot> by 2 given 
 *       indices and insert or replace it's content with text and/or HTML.
 * @param {string<CSS selector>} selector - Reference to the <table> or it's children       
 * @param {number} row - Index of the <tr> of target cell
 * @param {number} col - Index of the target <td>/<th> 
 * @param {string<htmlString>} content - A string of HTML and/or text
 * @param {boolean} overwrite - If false, content is appended. If true, cell content will
 *        replaced with content
 * @default {boolean} overwrite - false
 */
function rowCol(selector, row, col, content, overwrite = false) {
  let table = document.querySelector(selector) ?? document.querySelector('table'); //➊
  let tGrp =
    table.tagName === 'TBODY' ? table :
    table.tagName === 'TABLE' ? table.tBodies[0] :
    table.tagName === 'THEAD' ? table :
    table.tagName === 'TFOOT' ? table : table.tBodies[0]; //➋
  if (overwrite) {
    tGrp.rows[row].cells[col].replaceChildren(); //➌
  }
  tGrp.rows[row].cells[col].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content); //➍
}


rowCol('table', 7, 3, ` <input placeholder="Enter text">`);
rowCol('tbody', 2, 0, `This is an overwrite`, true);
rowCol('.test', 9, 5, `<br>Last row and column`);
rowCol('thead', 0, 4, `Fifth column`, true);
rowCol('table', 6, 3, `<a href='example.com'>Example.com</a>`, true);
rowCol('t', 5, 1, `If the first parameter is wrong, it's OK as long as it's a string`, true);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class='test'>
  <thead> 
    <tr><th>TEST</th><th>TEST</th><th>TEST</th><th>TEST</th><th>TEST</th><th>TEST</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var newAssignment = [
    "Col 0",
    "Col 1",
    "Col 2",
    "Mark",
    "C Col4",
    "B Col5",
    "Col 6"
  ];
  
  newAssignment[4] = newAssignment[4].split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
  newAssignment[5] = newAssignment[5].split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
  
  $('#courses-table tr').each(function(i, row) {
    if ($("td:eq(6)", row).text() == newAssignment[3]) { // check courses
      console.log("First Hit");
      if ($("td:eq(5)", row).text() == newAssignment[5]) { // check route
        console.log("Second Hit");
        if ($("td:eq(4)", row).text() == newAssignment[4]) { // check semester
          console.log("Third Hit");
          console.log($("td:eq(3)", row).text());
          $("td:eq(0)", row).html("TEST");
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="courses-table" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
      <td>Col 3</td>
      <td>Col4</td>
      <td>Col5</td>
      <td>Col 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
      <td>Col 3</td>
      <td>Col4</td>
      <td>Col5</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
      <td>Col 3</td>
      <td>Col4</td>
      <td>Col5</td>
      <td>Col 6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This turns it all into jQuery instead of a mix. I used `i` and `row` for Index and Element in the `.each()` callback. Now we can select the Cells as needed and perform the tests.